# How to handle next steps/card authentication when working with subscriptions?

Tags: stripe-payments

Note: I'm using the [`Node.js` SDK](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node), but I assume all Stripe SDKs are thin wrappers around their REST API.

How can I handle card authentication/3D-Secure/next steps when working with subscriptions and receiving a `status == incomplete` after creating a new subscription?

The documentation isn't very clear about it. It seems that [`Subscription`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions) objects are a higher-order abstraction over [`PaymentIntent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) objects, with recurring charges, free trial days, things like this.

However, it seems to be impossible to actually work with a [`PaymentIntent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) once you've created a subscription. And the only way to retrieve a [`PaymentIntent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) seems to be by using its associated `pi_` ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the [Build a subscription guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription) on Stripe's documentation? Specifically [this](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=elements#collect-payment) section, where you collect payment details and confirm the Payment Intent returned on the Subscription object in your applications front-end.